# Why doesn't this question count

Tags: support, site-promotion, diablo-3

I have this question

[System Requirements](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/65394/whats-the-definition-of-broadband)

but according to my home page it does not seem I am getting credit for this question.  Who do I contact about this.

BTW, there was no "contest" type tag, and I can not create new tags?

[image]

Comment: I tried to delete the question.  but could not

Comment: Yep, once a question has answers, it is essentially "community property", and you are not able to unilaterally delete it.  Did you want to delete it just so that you could re-ask for the contest, or was there some other reason?

Comment: yep and the "community" doesn't have a problem down voting this even more after I admit my mistake :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @bwarner said in [his answer](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4722/12936)

> **The question was asked before the start period of the contest.**
>
> The contest starts on Monday, May 14 11:00 PM UTC and ends on Friday,
>   Jun 1 11:00 PM UTC.

Your questions and your answers are only available to the contest after this date and before the contest end. Take a look at [the content post](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4651/diablo-3-acts-and-gems-battle-the-armies-of-hell-with-us-and-earn-awesome-priz) for more info.

There is no contest tag. In this case, you must create questions with the tag [diablo-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo-3) or answer questions with this tag. Doing it, you automatically enter the contest.

When you have questions about the functionality of the Gaming Stack Exchange, go for [our meta](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 6):

The question was asked before the start period of the contest.

> The contest starts on Monday, May 14 11:00 PM UTC and ends on Friday,
>   Jun 1 11:00 PM UTC.